# How can I validate if a variable is between two specified numbers?

Tags: python, validation

How can I validate user input to restrict them in only entering numerical values between -5 and -21? I currently have this while loop set up;

```
while True: 
 if flatNumber.isdigit():
      flatNumber = int(flatNumber)
      if flatNumber>5 and flatNumber<21: 
           print("Enjoy your stay.") 
           break 
      else:  
           flatNumber = input("Please enter your flat number.")
 else: 
    flatNumber = input("Please enter a numerical flat number.")
```

However this only validates numerical values between 5 and 21? Can someone please post a solution and explain it as to how I can validate numerical values between -5 and -21?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simplified chained comparison using negative values:

```
if -21 < flatNumber < -5:
```

`str.isdigit` won't work for negative numbers, you should almost always use a try/except when validating input:

```
while True:
    try: 
        # try to cast to int
        flatNumber = int(input("Please enter your flat number."))
        # if cast was successful make sure it is in range if not ask again
        if not -21 < flatNumber < -5:
            print("Not in range -5 to -21")
            continue
        break # else all is good break the loop
    except ValueError:
           print("Invalid input")

print(flatNumber)
```

Comment: I tried using it however in the if statement above it I validate to see if it is indeed an integer. It seems as though flatNumber.isdigit() wont return as true for negative integers. Could you explain a solution?

Comment: ah ok one sec, this is why you should not use isdigit to validate input!

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just change the numbers and the directions of the inequalities? Like so:

```
if flatNumber<-5 and flatNumber>-21:
```

Comment: No I tired using it and entering "-7" when prompted by the message but "Please enter a numerical flat number." was printed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want exclusive test like you +5 to +21:

```
if flatNumber<-5 and flatNumber>-21: 
           print("Enjoy your stay.") 
           break 
      else:
```

If you want inclusive test

```
if flatNumber<=-5 and flatNumber>=-21: 
           print("Enjoy your stay.") 
           break 
      else:
```

Answer (score 0):

**if flatNumber>-21 and flatNumber<-5:**

**Remember that -5 is greater than -21.**

Answer (score 0):

modify this line like

```
if flatNumber<-5 and flatNumber>-21:
```